# Class cast exception on look up of JPA EntityManager on weblogic

Tags: jpa, ejb, weblogic

I am trying to lookup EntityManager using below code in MDB, but am getting below error. I have googled it but I could not getting anything out of it.
is this due to any jars problem, please guide me some pointers.

I am using weblogic version 12.1.3.

In JNDI tree -> I have JNDI name "jpaem", also I noticed it, for this JNDI - it showing the Class: 
**weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_12130_WLStub**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_12130_WLStub cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManager
    at JNDITest.main(JNDITest.java:33)

EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) context.lookup("jpaem");

My persistance.xml    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="Eclipselink_JPA" transaction-type="JTA">
            <jta-data-source>jpaem</jta-data-source>
            <class>jpa.Faxerror</class>
            <properties>
                <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle" />
                <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" value="jpaem"/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [all the possible ways of acquiring an EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/usclient005.htm#CIHIAHIE), if you have no specific reason to look up the EntityManager manually, I'd go with the easier

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Eclipselink_JPA")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Note that it's referencing the `name` attribute of your `persistence-unit`, declaration, not your `jta-data-source`. Looking that up will return a data source, not an entity manager, of course.